# How to use Auto Increment in Entity Framework 5, when seeding data?

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to seed data to my database after each database schema update , but  I have trouble solving an issue with my seeding functionality. My (value) class looks like this

```
public class ObjectInstance
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ObjectInstanceId { get; set; }
   
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ObjectInstanceTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I have set the necessary attributes on my key column - I think.

In my `DbContext` I have the following function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectClass>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(e => e.ObjectClassId);
            b.Property(e => e.ObjectClassId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(0, 1);

            b.HasData(
                new ObjectClass
                {
                    ObjectClassTitle = "Object",
                    ObjectClassDescription = "Root object",
                    OfType = 1
                },
                new ObjectClass
                {
                    ObjectClassTitle = "Object",
                    ObjectClassDescription = "Root object",
                    OfType = 1
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

No matter what I try to do, I get the following error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'ObjectClass' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'ObjectClassId'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - the error message **tells you** what to do - *Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.* - have you tried that?

Comment: Yes and it worked fine. I guess I will have to manually input the ID.